# File copy stops to ask about properties that can't be copied to new location

Tags: windows-8, file-transfer

I'm copying files from my Windows Home Server (v1) to a new Windows 8 box. So far when copying certain music and movie files the copy process has stopped to ask if I want to continue on because some properties can't be copied to the new location.

[image: Interrupted Action]

What properties can't be copied?

Comment: I saw that question and it didn't answer the question.

Comment: Copy it anyway and check the tags. If we have some more details maybe we can figure out why. What are the file systems?

Comment: "I saw that question and it didn't answer the question" - So? That doesn't make this any less of a duplicate. If you want to draw attention to an existing question, consider adding a bounty.

Comment: Well the other question already had an accepted answer that I didn't feel answered my question. Plus my file systems could have been different. Without completely editing the other person's question how am I supposed to get an answer. I already feel there is a better answer already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On NTFS, files can have more than one stream of data. Usually there's only one, the default, data stream.

Windows 2000 and XP used to use alternate streams to store additional properties which you could add in Summary tab of Properties dialog. This feature has been deprecated since Windows Vista. Yet you may still have files with such properties.

The warning is displayed when you copy a file which has alternate streams from NTFS drive to a drive that does not support alternate data streams. Therefore the alternate streams will be lost.

Usually it's rather safe to ignore this warning.
Anyway, in most cases, you can't use that data.

---

Windows also uses alternate data streams to mark files as *downloaded from the Internet*.

To see the list of alternate streams, you can use [Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) utility. Run the following in Command Prompt:

```
streams.exe streams.exe

...
<path-to>\Streams\streams.exe:
   :Zone.Identifier:$DATA       26
```

You can see the data in the stream by using this command:

```
more <streams.exe::Zone.Identifier:$DATA
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

When you run an application marked as downloaded from the Internet, Windows displays a warning.

If you open the properties of `streams.exe`, you will see **Unblock** button in the **Security** section of the **General** tab. If click this button, the alternate stream will be deleted, and the above command, `streams.exe streams.exe`, will produce empty output.

Comment: Thanks, checked out the files using that utility. Those files were placed on the file server from a Mac and had Apple Meta data in the streams (AFP_AfpInfo and AFP_Resource). They are not there once copied but I don't think I will need them. Thanks again.